# Prevent external sites from accessing my ashx pages

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I have my business logic code stored in .ashx files. I send a POST request to create data, and a GET request to retrieve JSON data, when is then displayed in a page.

My question is: How do I prevent Joe Nobody from directly calling my .ashx pages and creating a user, modifying data, retrieving data, etc.

Does every .ashx page need some "login check"? Or is there a more site-wide way of accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you place all of your ASHX files in the same folder you should be able to DENY anonymous access to that folder to achieve what you want.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. So to clarify, that is done at the IIS level? And that would prevent any external sites from accessing my ASHX files without having to write otherwise redundant verification code in each page?

Comment: you could do it via web.config

Answer (score 1):

You could restrict access to your folder via web.config

```
<location path="CustomerFolder">
<system.web>

<authorization>
<allow roles="Admin, Customers"/> //Allow users in Admin and Customers roles

<deny users="*"/> // Deny rest of all
</authorization>

</system.web>
</location>
```